# Iterating Conditions through Pandas .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I just wanted to ask the community and see if there is a more efficient to do this.

I have several rows in a data frame and I am using .loc to filter values in row A for I can perform calculations on row B.

I can easily do something like...

```
filter_1 = df.loc['Condition'] = 1
```

And then perform the mathematical calculation on row B that I need.

But there are many conditions I must go through so I was wondering if I could possibly make a list of the conditions and then iterate them through the .loc function in less lines of code?

Would something like this work where I create a list, then iterate the conditions through a loop?

Thank you!

This example gets most of what I want. I just need it to show 6.4 and 7.0 in this example. How can I manipulate the iteration for it shows the results for the unique values in row 'a'?

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
b = [5,1,3,5,7,20,9,5,8,4]

col = ['a', 'b']

list_1 = []

for i, j in zip(a,b):
    list_1.append([i,j])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list_1, columns= col)

for i in a:
    aa = df1[df1['a'].isin([i])]
    aa1 = aa['b'].mean()
    print (aa1)
```

Comment: Please explain better. Which condition?

Comment: Filtering row A for values between 1 and 10 would work for now.  I just need to look at each value in the range and perform the calculation on row B. A simple calculation such as a mean or standard deviation. I am doing a simple statistical analysis here on row B based on the many conditions that I have to filter on row A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution using set

```
set_a = set(a)

for i in set_a:
    aa = df[df['a'].isin([i])]
    aa1 = aa['b'].mean()
    print (aa1)
```

## Solution using pandas mean function

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
b = [5,1,3,5,7,20,9,5,8,4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b})

print (df)

print(df.groupby('a').mean())
```

The results from this are:

Original Dataframe df:

```
   a   b
0  1   5
1  2   1
2  1   3
3  2   5
4  1   7
5  2  20
6  1   9
7  2   5
8  1   8
9  2   4
```

The mean value of df['a'] is:

```
     b
a     
1  6.4
2  7.0
```

Comment: Yes! That's perfect. Thank you. Just for practice, how would I change my for loop above for I could get these results?

Comment: you can do `set_a = set(a)`. It will give you a result of `[1,2]`. Then you are searching for it only once. Let me get you the code for that so you can compare and see if its aligned.

Comment: if I answered your question, please up vote and mark as answered. Please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: @A.J.Nock, i have provided you code that will print the same using your loop code. See if this matches your code. Good luck with your learning. You are doing great.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
df = df[(df['A'] > 1) & (df['A'] < 10)]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I just posted an iteration which mostly accomplishes what I am trying to do. I now just need it to only print once for each unique value.